# VMware Workstation 11: how to automatically shut down host computer when Guest OS is shut down?

Tags: automation, vmware-workstation

I've Googled and Googled and tapped out my entire IT network, so here I am.

Environment: Windows 7 Pro. as the host computer, Windows XP as the guest OS on VMware Workstation 11.

How can I trigger the host computer to shut down automatically when the Guest OS is powered off? I was thinking of writing a batch script and deploying it through the Task Scheduler, but I can't find an Event ID to link it. I was also considering making VMware Workstation a service so that, once closed, it would trigger Windows to shut down, but I don't know if that's a viable solution. Does anyone have any suggestions, or could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do the guest OS and host OS share a drive/folder where a indicator file can be placed? Right now I don't have a Vmware workstation in handy. But the event IDs [6006 (normal shutdown), 6008 (system failure) and 6005 (rebooted)](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1007866) look promising

Answer (score 2):

You could use Group/Local Policies to setup a shutdown script in the XP guest that uses Windows' `shutdown`, or perhaps [PSShutdown](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psshutdown.aspx) (my preference), to launch a delayed shutdown down of the host computer.

Something like `psshutdown \\hostcomptuer -s -t 120` would launch a shutdown of the host in 2 minutes.

Comment: that would work, but why not just use `shutdown`?

Comment: @Keltari Yeah they could, I just find PSShutdown is easier to deal with, especially when targeting remote computers, and using longer delay times.  Mostly personal preference I guess. ;)

Comment: Good solution. Just want to add: If the guest and host system are not in the same network one could use the [host-only network adapter](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_hostonly.html)